# How to populate data for SharePoint Team Foundation Server web part burndown, bug progress chart

Tags: tfs

We are configuring the Team Foundation Server web part to show dashboards associated with burndown, user stories, etc. I added some active but when I click on the Bug Progress link, the chart does not display any data. I click on the Burndown link to add some issues data. When I click on the Task burndown or the  user story progress, I get the following message

﻿﻿"The error occured during an attempt to establish a connection to the external data source. The following connections failed to refresh:

TfsOlaReport"

I would like the see the data correctly populated in the chart. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your administrator to fix this.

They likely need to validate the configuration and then rebuild the data warehouse and cube.

This usually occurs because a DBA thinks that they know how to configure SQL, RS, or AS better than Microsoft. They don't, and should not have permission to any of the TFS subsystems. TFS owns and manages its subsystems itself. Don't change anything outside of the TFS Admin Console without direct direction from the Product Team.